# Regex-activated snippet in VSCode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I want to create a snippet that activates using a regex, i.e. if I type

```
\begin{environment}
```

VSCode automatically inserts

```
\end{environment}
```

Or, for another example, typing

```
{% block jinjablock %}
```

results in

```
{% endblock jinjablock %}
```

For any values of `environment` or `jinjablock`.

This seems to already be a thing, as tag completion works when I type XML/HTML tags, but I'd like to extend it arbitrarily.
EDIT: Clarified examples

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Are you literally tying out the regex?  Or you just want to capture and reuse what you type after the `\begin{use this later}`?

Comment: @Mark Option 2. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg When I type a tag, for instance, <div>, VSCode autocompletes with </div>, similarly for all possible tags (even ones not defined by MDN; <notatag> is autocompleted with </notatag>). I want to extend this arbitrarily, to any pattern I specify.

Comment: And in what type of file?

Comment: @Mark Normally, this works with .html and .xml files, but I want to extend this to different patterns in .html files and to .tex files.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to go with snippets here.  In one of your snippets files:

```
"complete begin/end tags": {
    // "scope": "",  // put your language mode here, like javascriptreact, etc.
    "prefix": "\\begin",
    "body": [
        "\\begin{${1:environment}}",
        //  "",   // if you want an empty line between the blocks in the output
        "\\end{$1}"
    ],
    "description": "\\begin \\end"
},

"complete block/endblock tags": {
    // "scope": "",// put your language mode here, like javascriptreact, etc.
    "prefix": "%",
    "body": [
        "{% block ${1:jinjablock} %}",
        "{% endblock $1 %}"
    ],
    "description": "{% block {% endblock"
},
```

Reload vscode after making these changes!

[image: complete blocks]

As you can see in the demo, sometimes vscode has trouble recognizing just `%` as a snippet prefix.  So I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to bring up the suggestions.

Comment: I know how to make snippets, thanks. I've switched to Vim and UltiSnips. I don't understand why automatic expansion isn't a feature in VSCode (for that matter, anything that isn't UltiSnips).